# GWT celltable : editable cell size increases when clicked

Tags: gwt

I have a celltable in my GWT application which have editable cells , when i click on any editable cell in my celltable , it bocomes editable + it also increase its size a lot..

Is there any way i can avoid this change of width of the editable cell when clicked ..hed

attached are two images , one before click on the cell and other after click on the cell .. 
 can see the whole celltable width changes .. I want to avoid this and want to keep the size constant even after i click on the editable cell

[image]

[image: After Click]

Comment: Are you using a `fixed-width` layout for your `CellTable`?

Comment: I am usign something like this .. cellTable.setWidth("99%");
  cellTable.setTableLayoutFixed(true);

Comment: Try with 100%, and have a look at [here](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCellTable#columnWidths), if you haven't already.

Comment: just changing to 100% , resolved the issue :) , thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a 100% fixed-layout table, either using

```
cellTable.setWidth("100%", true);
```

or

```
cellTable.setWidth("100%");
cellTable.setTableLayoutFixed(true);
```

Fixed-layout and column width is explained [here](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCellTable#columnWidths).